# Amazon EC2 MySQL Failed to Start

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm having issues starting MySQL after it randomly stopped working a few minutes ago. I'm getting this error while trying to connect:

```
Connect failed: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

So I tried to restart MySQL (this had worked for me before) and I got this:

```
Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]
```

Here's my error log:

```
130414 20:03:45 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130414 20:03:45 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130414 20:03:45 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130414 20:03:45  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130414 20:03:46  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130414 20:03:46  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
```

Can anyone offer some tips? I'm pretty noobish at this server stuff :P

Comment: Wouldn't this have been better migrated to DBA.SE?

Comment: Do you have any other `ibdata1` or `ib_logfile0` or `ib_logfile1` files on your system?  You can use `locate ibdata1` or `sudo find / -name ibdata1` to find them.  (Note that the `locate` database is generated daily and won't have recently created files in it.)

Comment: Also, do you have backups?  I have a feeling you're going to need them.

Comment: I solved the issue by rebooting the EC2 virtual instance...weird.